# Map Caps Lock to change keyboard layout in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, remapping

I found `System Preferences → Keyboard → Modifier Keys` menu, but I can map other modifier key to it, not a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding answer of @mrded for macOS Sierra.

I used [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to remap `caps_lock` to `f19`. To this end I placed the following file `karabiner.json` to `~/.karabiner.d/configuration`:

```
{
    "profiles": [
        {
            "name": "Default profile",
            "selected": true,
            "simple_modifications": {
                "caps_lock": "f19"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I opened *Keyboard preferences → Shortcuts → Input sources* and selected `F19` as "Select the previous input source" option.

Note also that according to [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/swap-to-non-latin-keyboard-layouts-in-macos-sierra-with-1787279158), there is built-in feature in macOS Sierra to switch layouts with Caps Lock but it seem to work only with some layouts. (At least I don't see this feature for my layouts which are Ilya Birman's typographic Latin/Cyrillic.)

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work on macOS Sierra 10.12. When I press Caps Lock in _Input Sources_ while trying to change hotkey for input sources, nothing happens :(

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version of Mac OS X you are running (on 10.13.5 it's definitely possible).  System settings -> Keyboard -> Input sources -> checkbox about Caps Lock

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard language layout pair is English-Russian you can try to use [Punto Switcher from Yandex](https://yandex.ru/soft/punto) for Windows and Mac. It not about Caps, but about what you typing - for example it will automatically replace **ghbdtn** to **привет**.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) or [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) if you use Mac OS 10.12 Sierra.

The Idea is to overwrite Caps Lock with another useless key, lets say F13, and then use that key to change keyboard layout.

Comment: Only karabiner doesn't work with Sierra at the moment.

Comment: It works perfect on my Sierra.

Comment: only Karabiner-Elements worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, what you want to accomplish cannot be done with what OS X gives you. I have hacked a keyboard layout to switch to Cyrillic when Caps Lock is on, but it's a bit ugly - everything happens within the same actual keyboard layout (flag in menu bar does not change), and some apps behave funny with it (most shortcuts do not work in Mozilla-based software, for example). Ukelele is your friend here, as Felix pointed out, but I would love to find a true solution to have Caps Lock switch the actual layouts.